# What are wrong with this phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, questions, what

Is the phrase

> what are wrong with XY and ZZ

correct English? I stumbled upon it in a question on movies.SE: [What are wrong with the bleach and the fish in the Machinist?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/what-are-wrong-with-the-bleach-and-the-fish-in-the-machinist), and instantly thought "That has to be an error!"

Not being a native speaker, I thought before correcting it, it'd be better to Google it first (you never know) and it actually returned [over 13 million results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22what+are+wrong+with%22).

I'm stumped, is this actually correct? Or just a common mistake?

Comment: I edited your question to include the whole title within it, from which the phrase is (I think) obviously correct.  Verb "are" is used with plural bleach and fish; *what* may be singular or plural.

Comment: `from which the phrase is (I think) obviously correct.` Is it? From my logic the verb "is" is relating to the subject "what", which is singular. How can it be plural? _Something are wrong with XYZ_ sounds really wrong to me.

Comment: "the bleacn and the fish" is the object of "with", not the subject of "are".  So this sentence is (it seems to me) incorrect.  You could say: "What are the things wrong with ..."

Comment: 'What' in itself is neither singular nor plural; it does not change.  'Something are wrong' is odd because *something* -some **thing** -is singular.  And your formulation is subtly different from the example : *XYZ* would normally be assumed to be one thing (which does indeed take a singular verb), whereas *the bleach and the fish* are (see what I mean?) two different things.

Comment: Interesting question; personally I would have used "what things are wrong..." to clarify that the pronoun is used as plural. I have (astonishingly) never come across this term

Comment: @Rory Alsop: No disrespect, but I rejected your edit to the title. In the circumstances, it seems reasonable/amusing to me for OP to use the questionable *"what are"* there as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"What is wrong with XYZ?" is valid regardless of whether XYZ is one thing or many, and whether the questioner expects an answer detailing one fault or many.

If the questioner wanted to explicitly indicate that he expects an answer listing multiple faults, he'd have to say something like "What **things** are wrong with XYZ?".

"What **are** wrong with XYZ?" is *never* grammatically valid. Nor is it a common mistake — I don't recall seeing it before now, and Google Books records only [14 instances of "what are wrong with"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what%20are%20wrong%20with%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22what%20are%20wrong%20with%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=jI-MT_WZCsiv0QXL0omVDw&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=46decfdae1e76608&biw=1240&bih=902), compared to [millions of "what is wrong with"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what%20are%20wrong%20with%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22what%20is%20wrong%20with%22&oq=%22what%20is%20wrong%20with%22&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0.4177l153777l1l154209l10l5l5l0l0l0l83l333l5l10l0.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=46decfdae1e76608&biw=1240&bih=902).

As regards exactly *why* the non-standard usage is unacceptable, rather than just uncommon, *what* in this construction is a [non-count](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/noncount.htm) [pronoun](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090106144231AApUFKo). Non-count nouns [require the singular verb form](http://www.eslgold.com/grammar/subject_verb_agreement_quantifiers.html).

**Edit:** Kudos to JLG for highlighting the importance of the word *wrong* in this construction. The [interrogative pronoun](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-interrogative.htm) *what* attaches to *wrong* — a non-count [abstract noun](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/abstractnoun.htm) which transfers its non-count status to *what*. That doesn't happen with, for example, "What are those things?".

Comment: I agree that it's not correct to say "what *are* wrong with." See this NGram: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+are+wrong+with%2C+what+is+wrong+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: Why would you think that 'what' is non-count because of this example? 'What' doesn't get filled in by XYZ. 'What' is a kind of wrong not a kind of XYZ. 'What -are- wrongs made by XYZ?' is grammatical because the verb agrees with 'wrongs'.

Comment: @Mitch: I don't follow you. *'What are wrongs made by XYZ?'* sounds like a bad translation. I stand by my assertion that "what" in this usage is a "non-count pronoun". Thus, since non-count nouns always take the singular verb form, OP's version is grammatically incorrect. If you think *"What are wrong with X [Y and Z]"* can ever be valid then **please** post an answer defending it, and see if you can get anyone else to agree - I certainly won't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think "what are wrong with X,Y,and Z" is correct at all. But I disagreed with your analysis. My sentence, on reflection, is both bad and doesn't point to the right analysis either. Whatever is going on, the phrase 'with XYZ' is disposable and so the number of XYZ cannot have anything to do with the number on the verb.

Comment: @Mitch: Isn't "whatever is going on" the fact that the word *wrong* is thrown in there? "What is wrong..." is correct; "What are wrong..." is incorrect. It doesn't matter whether the object of the preposition "with" is plural or singular.

Comment: @JLG: I think that was what I was trying to say that the object of the preposition "with" is irrelevant, because the prepositional phrase is optional. But 'wrong' isn't thrown in there; I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Mitch: What JLG said. I know perfectly well that the plurality or otherwise of XYZ is irrelevant - I pointed it out explicitly because it wasn't obvious to me why OP thought he should use the plural verb form, so I covered both lines of reasoning he *might* have followed. The word *wrong* is the target of *what* - requesting that some thing(s) should be identified.

Comment: @Mitch: Sorry if that wasn't clear. I meant what Jay says in his answer. The word "wrong" makes the verb singular; the object of the preposition has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @JLG: I think you're absolutely right. I've been happily saying that in context, "what" is a non-count pronoun, but of course, the "context" is the word *wrong*. I'll edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

"What" can be either singular or plural. "is/are" is a linking verb, so the number of the things on either side -- the subject and the predicate nominative -- should match, and then this number should match the verb.

So, for example, we say, "What IS the name of your friend?" because "name" is singular, so "what" is being used as a singular, so the verb should be singular. But we say, "What ARE the names of your friends?" because "names" is plural, etc.

In this case we have a predicate adjective rather than a predicate nominative. I think in such cases the subject "what" is always considered singular. I'm trying to think of exceptions. So in "What is/are wrong with X, Y, and Z", we should use "is". I guess you are being thrown off by the prepositional phrase "with X, Y, and Z". But such a phrase does not affect the number of the subject. A simple rule of thumb is, when trying to determine things about the subject and verb, just ignore any "extra detail" phrases.

If that doesn't make sense to your intuition, consider this sentence, "Who is/are the policeman who arrested Smith and Jones?" Clearly it should be "is", because "policeman" is singular -- we are asking for one policeman. The fact that "Smith and Jones" are two people is irrelevant. They're not the "who" here: "the policeman" is.

In the same way, the thing you are asking about in your sentence is "wrong". The fact that it is "with X, Y, and Z" has nothing to do with the number of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

As a pronoun, **what** derives its number from the noun it replaces. In our sentence ('What is/are wrong with X, Y and Z?') it is not clear whether **what** replaces **thing** or **things** (or any number of other singular/plural nouns).

I would offer that **is** provides a more natural construction and is thus to be preferred: 'What is wrong with X, Y and Z?'

In my brief research, I was not able to find a conclusive answer based on grammaticality, though I am somewhat swayed by the comments by @JLG (about the non-count status of **wrong**).

Pocket Fowler's Modern English Usage says this:

> **singular** ***what.***
>
> A problem of singular or plural verb agreement arises when what is
> singular but looks forward to a plural noun or pronoun later in the
> sentence: What we need is/are clear guidelines. Fowler had a useful
> rule that if the sentence begins in the singular (i.e. if the initial
> what is singular), the continuation should also be singular; so the
> example just given would be expressed in the form What we need is
> clear guidelines. In current use this rule is often respected, as the
> following examples show:
>
> "What really worries me is the numbers—Nina Bawden, 1987"
>
> "What bothered him was drivers who switched lanes without signalling—New Yorker, 1989."
>
> In these cases, it is arguable that a noun phrase such as the
> circumstance of or the fact of should be understood after the main
> verb; it is not the numbers or the drivers as such that cause the
> worry in the first example or the bother in the second, but the fact
> of what they represented or were doing. There are, however, counter
> examples to be found:
>
> "What concerns me are the number of construction projects that are delayed—York Press, 2004 [OEC]."
>
> **plural** ***what.***
>
> A different situation arises when what is plural: I have few books,
> and what there are do not help me. In this sentence, what refers back
> to books, and so its plural status is clear. When what refers forward,
> the choice is less obvious: We seem to have abandoned what seem/seems
> to us to be the most valuable parts of our Constitution. Fowler (whose
> example this is) had another useful rule in these cases: if what can
> be resolved into the—s that, with—s standing for a plural noun that
> comes later in the sentence, the construction should be plural. In the
> example just given, what…can be resolved into the parts of our
> Constitution that…, and the continuation should therefore be seem
> (plural), not seems. If the relative clause introduced by what comes
> at the head of the sentence, the same rule can be followed if what can
> be resolved into that which: What [= that which] is required is faith
> and confidence, and willingness to work. This principle is much less
> secure, however, since what in the example given (Fowler's again) can
> as easily be resolved as the things which (plural): What [= the things
> which] are required are faith and confidence, and willingness to work.
> Here there is clearly a choice, and naturalness and rhythm will often
> be decisive; the important point is that the choice between singular
> and plural should be consistent throughout the sentence, and that a
> singular what should not be followed by a plural continuation: ☒ What
> is required are faith and confidence, and willingness to work.